# CSS logo, text and image auto resize?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to ensure that as the browser scales it's zoom up or down, that the image and text scale proportional to that. Currently the image stays small while the text grows, so ratio is off. I've tried object-fit, etc. to no avail.

[image]

I want the glasses to be vertically aligned to the center next to the text and to scale to the proportions shown.

### Attempt

```html
    <div className={styles["sidebar"]}>
      <div id={styles["logo"]}>
        ForLater
        <img height="50px" width="auto" src="/logo.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
#logo {
    font-family: calgary-script-ot, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #40486E;
    box-shadow: 11px -1px 27px -14px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 11px -1px 27px -14px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);
    -moz-box-shadow: 11px -1px 27px -14px rgba(0,0,0,0.48);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working [repro] for full debugging details. CSS alone is useless in mostc ases withotu the corresponding HTML markup.

Comment: Added html markup